# How to join DataFrames and get max of particular column?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two PySpark DataFrames `df1` and `df2`. They have the same names of columns but might have a different number of rows. Also, some combinations of  may not exist in one of DataFrames.

```
df1 =
wpk  ipk  num
1    2    23.4
1    3    45.5
2    1    0.0

df2 =
wpk  ipk  num
1    1    12.0
1    3    40.0
2    1    50.0
```

I want to obtain a new DataFrame `df` that is the result of the outer joining of `df1` and `df2`. The `df` should have the same columns, but the column `num` should be the max of `df1` and `df2`.

The expected result is this one:

```
wpk  ipk  num
1    1    12.0
1    2    23.4
1    3    45.5
2    1    50.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if this is suitable for your problem, however this would be how I would achieve the specified result.

```
import pandas as pd

df3 = df1.append(df2).groupby(['wpk','ipk'])['num'].max()
```

Comment: In Spark, it'll be `df1.union(df2).groupBy($"wpk", $"ipk").agg(max($"num")).show`

Comment: Will, I am asking about PySpark, not Pandas.

Comment: @philantrovert: If I had multiple numerical columns, could I do something like `agg(max($"num"),max($"num2"))`?

Comment: @Dinosaurius yeah, this is the definition `def agg(expr: Column, exprs: Column*): DataFrame`